# How to rewrite an HTML file in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML file and I want to rewrite some of the "a href" tags and write into other HTML file.

How can I do that in PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: please ask something specific.

Comment: Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) < horrible answer, horrible comment, don't do that. Do tell us what it is you're trying to do...

Comment: Thanks for the assumption that we are brainreaders, but sorry, no dice. Unless you don't detail your question, it will get closed...

Comment: 1. PHP can open text files (and also .html files), so read in the file
2. Parse the file, searching for "<a href="
3. Modify the link using php's string functions
4. write the file back out to another .html file

I personally would not use php for this task, as it is slow and not well suited to it. On the serverside, use something like awk/sed or perl or even python, perhaps even time it using a cron task if its something periodical.

Comment: What details and "something specific" do you need? I was just simply asking about reading / writing HTML files and rewriting "a href" tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the content from first page
2. Replace / add / remove tags you wants to
3. Write the content in new page.